# AWS CodePipeline with BitBucket source

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

we're having issues connecting our BitBucket to CodePipeline.
I can setup the connection, but i don't get any repos listed.
Even if I type in the name, it cannot find it.
After manually typing i can save and run, but it fails with error: make sure repo exists.

If I setup the connection in CodeBuild it's working.
I tested in eu-central-1 and eu-west-1

Anybody with a similar issue?

Best regards,
Kai

Comment: Which Bitbucket account owns the repository you're trying to use? Is it the same Bitbucket account you used to create the connection in CodePipeline?

Comment: I had the same problem. After spending few hours, I got to know that. The repository should belong to your own workspace. If you create a workspace then all the repositories inside that workspace is visible in codepipeline, repositories belonging to other workspaces which isn't created by you is not displayed even if you have admin privileges for that repository. This is a dumb feature which Atlassian-AWS should change.